# I'm creating an Map Searching app through an Youtube tutorial but my app getting crashed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, crash

I am trying to create an app through a Youtube tutorial, but my app is getting crashed whenever I submit location in SearchView.

I have tried to change import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView; from import android.widget.SearchView;

````
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.location);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                if (location != null || location != "") {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }
}```

"I expect that the app would not crash when I again hit enter to submit search in SearchView."
````

Comment: Can you post the error trace printed in the debug console? It is hard to help you without knowing where the app actually crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`if (location != null || location != "")`

To

`if (location != null || !location.equals(""))`

We can't compare a string as I did before.

Answer (score 0):

Add the stacktrace to the question to make it easier to identify the problem, but looking at the code if **geocoder.getFromLocationName (location, 1)** is null then **Address address = addressList.get (0)** will cause a NullPointerException